# YouTube Video Signature

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have been working on a YouTube downloader and I have most of the parts working.

Certain videos (ie Vevo videos) have ciphered signatures such as:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2AC41dglnM`

So I find the video's player and get the javascript for it:

`https://youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflchU0AK/base.js`

With that I grab the Signature function and Object:

```
var BE={
    lW:function(a,b){
        var c=a[0];
        a[0]=a[b%a.length];
        a[b]=c
    }, 
    e9:function(a){
        a.reverse()
    },
    TM:function(a,b){
        a.splice(0,b)
    }
};

CE=function(a){
    a=a.split("");
    BE.lW(a,58);BE.TM(a,1);
    BE.e9(a,63);BE.TM(a,2);
    BE.lW(a,8);
    BE.lW(a,21);
    return a.join("")
};
```

I take the s= from the YouTube video and run it through the CE function:

```
CE("02753A38F9C9290D0778202DC28B1DFA0F291DF67.A9DECBE95FE5A74123D0FC22527374E2F2501FBCBC")
```

then I try to replace the s= in the url:

```
https://r15---sn-5uaeznls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=yt6&itag=43&mm=31&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&source=youtube&mime=video%2Fwebm&expire=1493019580&dur=0.000&lmt=1365515278685092&ip=173.48.112.179&gcr=us&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1492997904&id=o-ACO6aSSDctHIeB2fsnvl0R4IpaSTeVBeBYxVwHiVSJg5&mn=sn-5uaeznls&gir=yes&clen=32929005&initcwndbps=887500&ipbits=0&upn=ywp8mm27sXc&pl=16&ei=XFf9WPWhNYmC8gSk3wU&s=66482ABA143BFD4DF419B22142266495EF11A26D.81873834D2C06DEAFFC33A22127DE1841BAD4676
```

But I'm still getting "Access Denied" from YouTube.
Am I using the deciphered signature correctly? Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: If you're getting access denied that's because you're not allowed to access it. How are you using the URL you get?

Comment: Youtube blocks cross-origin requests.

Comment: I'm using the url in chrome to test it. The access denied occurs because of the invalid signature.

Answer (score -1):

You 're doing it right, except that you have to add  the word "signature" and not "s" in the url.

An example would be:

```
https://r15---sn-5uaeznls.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=yt6&itag=43&mm=31&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&source=youtube&mime=video%2Fwebm&expire=1493019580&dur=0.000&lmt=1365515278685092&ip=173.48.112.179&gcr=us&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1492997904&id=o-ACO6aSSDctHIeB2fsnvl0R4IpaSTeVBeBYxVwHiVSJg5&mn=sn-5uaeznls&gir=yes&clen=32929005&initcwndbps=887500&ipbits=0&upn=ywp8mm27sXc&pl=16&ei=XFf9WPWhNYmC8gSk3wU&signature=66482ABA143BFD4DF419B22142266495EF11A26D.81873834D2C06DEAFFC33A22127DE1841BAD4676
```

Comment: It won't work man.  "s" is encrypted token which when decipher will result into signature.

Comment: did you find an answer ?